# Best model field to use for a 128-bit UUID in Django

Tags: python, django

In Django what model field is best use to store an orderable UUID that comprises of...

> [32-bit timestamp high]-[16-bit timestamp mid]-[16-bit timestamp low]-[16 bits random]-[48 bits random]

At the moment I'm using a `CharField` below is there something better fitted?

```
id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=28, unique=True,default=make_key)
```

Comment: The Model fields reference page is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/), with the different types defined [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#field-types). Click in the lower right to change to the version of Django you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django 1.8 introduced [UUIDField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.UUIDField). It uses UUID class from standard python library in which data is stored in different byte order from what you've presented, but as far as I know python UUID class can present UUID in various formats.

Prior to Django 1.8 you can use some third party package for that.

Comment: I'm using 1.8 so I guess UUIDField makes sense but, it does not state on that page how to modify the byte order.

Comment: Byte order in database must be as you mentioned in question? You can just use `bytes` or `bytes_le` method to choose which one to use.

Comment: Also source for your uuid can be anything. You don't need to stick with default, so bytes order won't matter.